# How to remove the clear button if an option is selected in select2 multiselect

Tags: java, jquery-select2

Hi people i am using select2 for some multiselect issues in my project. Here we create some documents and select2 is used in the create and edit form. If i open the document in the edit form i have done some changes in the dto(set selected = true) and them come preselected in the view. For this case i want that these selections must not be cleared. So i want not to show the clear button next to the label. Is there a way i can do this ? And if yes can i do it in the backend just like with the preselected ?

Comment: you can add a class and force them by that class , would be better if you provide your code

Comment: Well i fill the dropown with ajax request. In backend i have created a dto with these properties : id, text, selected. For example if i want the option to be preselected i set selected to true..Is there something i can also do in the backend?